# Unable to activate triggers in Azure Data Factory as part of CI/CD deployment

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I am deploying Azure Data Factory pipeline along with linked services and triggers via json templates. Even though the trigger has the **"runtime"** property as **"started"** in the template, the triggers are always deployed in the stopped state and have to be activated manually.

Code

```
{
    "name": "trigger-name-started",
    "properties": {
        "description": "some connection",
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Stopped",
        "pipelines": [
            {
                "pipelineReference": {
                    "referenceName": "pipeline-new",
                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 15,
                "startTime": "2022-12-03T09:53:00Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Unable to activate triggers in Azure Data Factory as part of CI/CD**
> **deployment ?**

If your trigger stopped before you start the deployment . Restart after deployment is complete.

Please follow [***continuous integration***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-automate-azure-pipelines#updating-active-triggers) using Azure Pipelines and also, you could use [***the PowerShell***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-sample-script) script for stopping triggers and update your trigger settings.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53153.azuredevops-cicd-for-azure-data-factory.aspx#Existing_CICD_Process_ARM_Template

http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2019/02/continuous-integration-and-delivery.html

Comment: Powershell script did the job, thanks a lot!